# jquery selector in variable

Tags: jquery, variables, selector

can someone explain why this jquery selector is not working, I've worked around the issue but for my sanity would like to know what I've got wrong

I have a form with multiple textareas, each gets an id like f_id_DSC000001.JPG where the last part is a photograph number, the textarea has an onblur event that uses post to send its contents and update a database table, a json response comes back. All of that works fine, I can see the results using Firebug, there are no problems there.

The DSC000001.JPG part of the id gets passed back in the json response as confirmation, then I want to change the class of the textarea to show the state of the update.

When I do this

```
var textarea_selector="#f_id_"+res_data.image_filename;
$(textarea_selector).removeClass("kw-class");
$(textarea_selector).addClass("update-failed");
```

the class does not change, but if I do this

```
$("textarea[id*='"+res_data.image_filename+"']").removeClass("kw-class");
                  $("textarea[id*='"+res_data.image_filename+"']").addClass("update-done");
```

it works fine.

I'm not a javascript / jquery expert :-( so a basic explanation is what I would really appreciate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a dot in your ID. And that’s interpreted as a [class selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#class-html):

```
#f_id_DSC000001.JPG
\_____________/\__/
 id             class
```

But this should work:

```
var textarea_element = document.getElementById("f_id_"+res_data.image_filename);
$(textarea_element).removeClass("kw-class").addClass("update-failed");
```

Or this:

```
var textarea_id = "f_id_"+res_data.image_filename;
$("[id="+textarea_id+"]").removeClass("kw-class").addClass("update-failed");
```

Comment: could have tried resolving it the jquery way. nevertheless +1 for spotting the mistake.

Comment: well spotted, I'll revisit the code. These responses are a great help to people like me who work alone.

Answer (score 1):

You have to be careful about escaping weird characters in your IDs. See [the jQuery FAQ](http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#How_do_I_select_an_element_that_has_weird_characters_in_its_ID.3F) for more.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you are calling two different ids. why are you appending "#f_id" in the first example? you should just be able to append '#' to the id of an element and select it just fine.

Comment: id*= means it should only contain that value, so you don't have to prepend anyhting...

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var textarea = $("textarea[id*='"+res_data.image_filename+"']");
textarea.removeClass("kw-class");
textarea.addClass("update-failed");
```

You're not constructing the selector the same as the example in your post, which is why it's failing. This solution you're only doing the select once.